# input values for FaceNet quantized with TensorFlow Lite

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am using the “FaceNet” model converted with “TensorFlow Lite” into a quantized model. It was done following the instructions on the page https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/facenet-on-mobile-cb6aebe38505.

This is the info on the input and the output buffer of the  quantized model.

```
INPUTS:
    [{'index': 451, 'shape': array([  1, 160, 160,   3], dtype=int32), 'quantization': (0.0078125, 128L), 'name': 'input', 'dtype': <type 'numpy.uint8'>}]
OUTPUTS:
    [{'index': 450, 'shape': array([  1, 512], dtype=int32), 'quantization': (0.0235294122248888, 0L), 'name': 'embeddings', 'dtype': <type 'numpy.uint8'>}]
```

I do not manage to fill the input buffer properly.

I have already used “FaceNet” FULL model, which takes float values and it worked as expected. So I know what input float values should look like for the full model, so I guess there is only one step more to convert each float value into a corresponding byte value and to feed those  byte values into the TensorFlow Lite model.

This is what I did with “FaceNet” FULL model.

```
//extract all the pixels of the image (of the face area of 160 x 160)
bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, inputWidth, 0, 0, inputWidth, inputHeight);

//copy the value of each channel of each pixel into an array
for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; ++i) {
    int p = intValues[i];

    shortValues[i * 3 + 2] = (short) (p & 0xFF);
    shortValues[i * 3 + 1] = (short) ((p >> 8) & 0xFF);
    shortValues[i * 3 + 0] = (short) ((p >> 16) & 0xFF);
}

//calculate the mean value of all the pixels of the image
double sum = 0f;
for (short shortValue : shortValues) {
    sum += shortValue;
}

double mean = sum / shortValues.length;

sum = 0f;
for (short shortValue : shortValues) {
    sum += Math.pow(shortValue - mean, 2);
}

//calculate the standard deviation of all the pixels of the image
double std = Math.sqrt(sum / shortValues.length);
double std_adj = Math.max(std, 1.0/ Math.sqrt(shortValues.length));

//FINALLY    fill the input buffer for the tensorflow 
//calculate a  float value for each pixel
for (short shortValue : shortValues) {
    inputFloatBuffer.put((float) ((shortValue - mean) * (1 / std_adj)));
}
```

}

Now that I have float values, how to convert them into byte values for TensorFlow Lite?

I tried every possible combination with the values “0.0078125” (1/128) and  “128”  (mentioned at the top of the post), but nothing gave meaningful results.

For example:

```
int int_value = ((short)(float_value * 128)) + 128;
```

I used scaling to squeeze float values first into the range of [-1,1], but that did not help either.

Does somebody have idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the model was quantized, but it really worth trying that directly putting the int value pixels you got from bitmap (in range [0, 255]) to the buffer. Make sure to use a `ByteBuffer` rather than `FloatBuffer` as well.